# If $f(z)$ has a power series expansion, how about $\exp(f(z))$ and what about its convergence?

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, power-series

If I have a function $f(z) = \sum a_k z^k$, and for example, then $e^{f(z)}$ should also has a power series expansion right? I can write $e^{f(z)} = \sum_i \frac{f(z)^i}{i!} = \sum_i \frac{1}{i!} (\sum_k a_k z^k)$.

My question is if I know the sum of the first 10 terms will give me error less than $0.1$, then what about the power series of $e^{f(z)}$ ? Is there any way I can analyze the convergence rate or radius of it? Thank you for any help.

Comment: The radius of convergence will be the same as that for $f(z)$, since $\exp$ is entire. Regarding the error term, the Lagrange form for instance will involve a higher derivative of $\exp(f(z))$.